# Windows Advanced System Settings console log as displayed in System Properties

Tags: windows, windows-10, cpu, console

I need to log to text file some of the items from Advances System Settings (Windows 10) with the exact text as displayed in Control Panet / System / Advanced System Settings. One important parameter is System - Processor.

I tried the command [`systeminfo`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/systeminfo) which is reportedly intended to do what I need.

The problem is that this command shows the text that is different from what is displayed in System Properties.

For example, in one of the systems where I tried this, the `systeminfo` shows the text like:

```
System Type:               x64-based PC
Processor(s):              1 Processor(s) Installed.
                           [01]: Intel64 Family 6 Model 79 Stepping 1 GenuineIntel ~2295 Mhz
Total Physical Memory:     16,384 MB
```

while the Control Panel shows the picture like:

[image]

As you can see, the text output does not show anything like `v4` and totally different at all.

The question is, is there an out-of-box built-in embedded windows console tool that is able see the Processor information in the same format and notation as Control Panel System settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Powershell Version**

Use `Get-CimInstance win32_processor`

```ps
Get-CimInstance CIM_Processor | select Name, MaxClockSpeed

Name                                     MaxClockSpeed
----                                     -------------
Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7200U CPU @ 2.50GHz          2712
```

**Command prompt**

Use `WMIC CPU Get Name, MaxClockSpeed`

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>WMIC CPU Get Name, MaxClockSpeed
MaxClockSpeed  Name
2712           Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7200U CPU @ 2.50GHz
```